# Last item only being added to db

Tags: c#

I am trying to add some controls to a list but for some reason its only saving the last view to the db.

```
public List<tblPortalIandEValue> createIandERecord(Guid _userId, string fieldName, string fieldValue)
{
    List<tblPortalIandEValue> _iandevalues = new List<tblPortalIandEValue>();
    _iandevalues.Add(new tblPortalIandEValue { userId = _userId, field_name = fieldName, field_value = fieldValue });

    return _iandevalues;
}
```

I think my problems lies in my save cause I'm calling this list add new and then returning it think I should be returning the record instead

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<tblPortalIandEValue> _iandevalues = new List<tblPortalIandEValue>();
    _customerId = Guid.NewGuid();
    _iandevalues=_dal.createIandERecord(_customerId , "mortagecic", mortagecic.Value.ToString());

    _iandevalues = _dal.createIandERecord(_customerId, "gascic", gascic.Value.ToString());
    _iandevalues = _dal.createIandERecord(_customerId, "electricitycic", electricitycic.Value.ToString());

    _iandevalues.ForEach(n =>_dal.portalEntities.tblPortalIandEValues.Add(n));
    _dal.portalEntities.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: The second line is overwriting the creation of the list. I suspect you want to change it to `_iandevalues.AddRange(_dal.createIandERecord(...));`

Comment: I belevie i am being stalked on hee no reason for the dowvote by someone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in your createIandERecord method since you are renewing the list everytime. change your code to this:

```
 public tblPortalIandEValue createIandERecord(Guid _userId, string fieldName, string fieldValue)
    {
        return new tblPortalIandEValue { userId = _userId, field_name = fieldName, field_value = fieldValue });
            }

    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<tblPortalIandEValue> _iandevalues = new List<tblPortalIandEValue>();
        _customerId = Guid.NewGuid();
        _iandevalues.Add(_dal.createIandERecord(_customerId, "mortagecic", mortagecic.Value.ToString()));

        _iandevalues.Add(_dal.createIandERecord(_customerId, "gascic", gascic.Value.ToString()));
        _iandevalues.Add(_dal.createIandERecord(_customerId, "electricitycic", electricitycic.Value.ToString()));
        _iandevalues.ForEach(n => _dal.portalEntities.tblPortalIandEValues.Add(n));
        _dal.portalEntities.SaveChanges();

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for helping instead of downvoating